# Is 'lackness' a valid word?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Firstly, I'm not a native speaker.

My question is about the word 'lackness'. I've heard it many times.
Is it a valid word or do we use just 'lack'?

For instance:

> "... lack of something..."?

Comment: Where have you heard it? Can you give an authentic example?

Comment: @BarrieEngland Giving an example for where ? It is not easy for me but I can say from non-native speaks such as me. 

Some non-native speakers feel themselves comfortable about using words. We are very productive for made up words!

In fact you get it even it is wrong. But I'm sure it does not sound good for natives. 

So I can't say where but I can give you list of names :)

Comment: When wondering if something is a word, try a dictionary.  If you *then* want to ask here, report your dictionary results with the question.

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry if you think this question dirtied here. In fact I've tried Google's translate. You can try it "lackness" in English side and the other side is Turkish. The first translate is "lackness" and the second one is "boşluğu doldurmak." It means "to feel the gap" .

Comment: 'lack' is enough.

Comment: Are you talking about the Lackness Monster?

Comment: No I'm talking about lackness family http://www.ancestry.com/name-origin?te=2&surname=lackness

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a word that does not exist in standard dictionaries, and is not a good neologism either.

Comment: It's not a 'word' in the sense it may not be listed in standard dictionaries. It may not be 'valid word' in the sense it differs from the more widely used and understood 'lack' in the sense that the OP uses it. However, there are definitely situations where the inflection is absolutely understandable and can be justifiably used without violating rules of grammar or causing ambiguity.

Comment: For that matter, the *-ness* suffix has been successfully applied to all kinds of words in many unexpected ways without raising any eyebrows at all.

Comment: Davut, try synonyms for "lack" or "void" which might be a better fit.  Your questions don't dirty this site at all.  If we can help, we do, or we can also recommend our sister site for English learners: ell.stackexchange.com :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'*Lackness*' is most definitely not a word.

You are trying to search for an *abstract noun* to show the scarcity of something, if I'm not mistaken. But in that context, 'lack' is the word to use, itself!

> "Lack of food left the kids in the shelter starved."
>   "The accused was acquitted due to lack of evidence against him."

P.S. You should try checking out [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Exactly - it is superfluous.

Comment: Forget superfluous, 'lackness' isn't even a word.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a native speaker and I wouldn't use that word.

In all of the instances I can imagine it being used ...

(e.g. "I can't write you a letter because of my lackness of pens")

... it is the noun OR verb, 'lack', and NOT 'lackness' which should be used ...

(e.g. "I can't write you a letter because I lack pens", "I can't write you a letter due to a lack of pens").

The verb 'to lack' can be used as an attributive verb, which often looks like an adjective...

(e.g. "That man is lacking trousers" is an alternative to "That man lacks trousers").

WOrds ending with -ness are usually nouns that have been formed from adjectives...

(e.g. "greatness", "blueness", etc)

But since lack is already a noun (it is also a verb) this is not necessary.

Comment: Both are good explanations. Thank you to @mikhailcazi for `ELL` page suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you might be hearing the word "likeness" instead.  It is the only legitimate word that seems close.